# new to android - what is the benefit of compiling with 'ant'?

Tags: java, android

I tried to look though the documentation but nothing explained why some android java apps are compiled with 'ant' vs. the normal way to to compile an app in eclipse?

Comment: Some good answers also explaining the "why" (despite the question) can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694846/how-to-use-ant

Comment: These days, I really wouldn't recommend using Ant. When you're graduating beyond the Eclipse default build process, Maven is a much more capable system.

Comment: what makes maven better than ant? and why should we even go the maven route when we have eclipse ?

Comment: Did you even look at the link? There are several reasons listed to use a build system such as Maven or ant instead of a normal build from within Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In basic words you can use `ant` to compile your Android project and get several *apks* as output, lets say for different companies. Like build machine. In `ant` you write all dependences and its easy to manage compilation process.

From my experience I used `ant` to bind Android NDK with SDK but Eclipse can do that pretty well.

So If you are not familiar with `ant`, use Eclipse for Android. It will be enough.

Some [link](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html) to start from